# Pandas не парсит некоторые сайты

Tags: python, pandas

pandas отказывается парсить некоторые сайты, например этот http://football.kulichki.net/italy/2017/teams/torino.htm

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'

Переставил bs4 (вместе с зависимостями, сейчас стоит версия 4.4.4), обновил пакеты ОС.
Стоят python 3.5, Ubuntu 16, pandas 0.17.1, pip 8.1.1, numpy 1.11, lxml: 3.5.0.  И, самое главное, другие сайты парсит нормально! Например этот http://statisticstimes.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось просто - надо было обновить bs4 до 4.6

Answer (score 1):

В Pandas v. 0.19.2 все работает "на ура":

```
dfs = pd.read_html('http://football.kulichki.net/italy/2017/teams/torino.htm')
```

Результат:

```
In [61]: dfs[1]
Out[61]:
     0                   1           2            3   4   5  6  7
0    №             Вратари   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
1    1     Даниэле Паделли  25.10.1985       Италия   2   -  -  -
2   21            Джо Харт  19.04.1987       Англия  36   -  2  -
3   99    Доменико Коппола  29.01.1999       Италия   -   -  -  -
4    №           Защитники   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
5    3   Кристиан Молинаро  30.07.1983       Италия  10   -  2  -
6    4      Леандро Кастан  05.11.1986     Бразилия  14   -  4  -
7    5              Карлао  19.01.1986     Бразилия   4   -  1  -
8    7  Давиде Дзаппакоста  11.06.1992       Италия  29   1  1  -
9   13     Лука Россеттини  09.05.1985       Италия  30   1  8  -
..  ..                 ...         ...          ...  ..  .. .. ..
20  15       Марко Бенасси  08.09.1994       Италия  27   5  5  -
21  16   Самуэль Густафсон  11.01.1995       Швеция   5   -  1  -
22  18   Мирко Вальдифиори  21.04.1986       Италия  24   -  5  -
23  22           Жоэль Оби  22.05.1991      Нигерия  20   -  3  -
24  25          Саша Лукич  13.08.1996       Сербия  14   -  5  -
25   №          Нападающие   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
26   9      Андреа Белотти  20.12.1993       Италия  35  26  5  -
27  11         Макси Лопес  03.04.1984    Аргентина  16   2  2  -
28  19         Хуан Итурбе  04.06.1993    Аргентина  16   1  1  -
29  31          Лукас Бойе  28.02.1996    Аргентина  30   1  5  -

[30 rows x 8 columns]

In [62]: dfs[2]
Out[62]:
     0               1           2            3    4    5    6    7
0    П          Игроки   Год рожд.  Гражданство    М    Г    Ж    К
1  NaN             NaN         NaN          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  Хосеф Мартинес  19.05.1993    Венесуэла   11    1    2    -
3  NaN     Чезаре Бово  14.01.1983       Италия    4    -    2    -
4  NaN  Джузеппе Вивес  14.07.1980       Италия    3    -    -    1
5  NaN    Маттиа Араму  14.05.1995       Италия    1    -    -    -

In [63]: dfs[3]
Out[63]:
      0           1                    2                    3
0   Тур        Дата             Соперник                 Голы
1     1  21.08.2016  Милан - Торино -...     Белотти, Баселли
2     2  28.08.2016  Торино - Болонья...  Белотти, Белотти...
3     3  11.09.2016  Аталанта - Торин...                  Яго
4     4  18.09.2016  Торино - Эмполи ...                  NaN
5     5  21.09.2016  Пескара - Торино...                  NaN
6     6  25.09.2016  Торино - Рома - 3:1    Белотти, Яго, Яго
7     7  02.10.2016  Торино - Фиорент...         Яго, Бенасси
8     8  17.10.2016  Палермо - Торино...  Ляйич, Ляйич, Бе...
9     9  23.10.2016  Торино - Лацио -...           Яго, Ляйич
..  ...         ...                  ...                  ...
29   29  18.03.2017  Торино - Интер -...       Баселли, Аскуа
30   30  02.04.2017  Торино - Удинезе...     Моретти, Белотти
31   31  09.04.2017  Кальяри - Торино...       Ляйич, Белотти
32   32  15.04.2017  Торино - Кротоне...              Белотти
33   33  23.04.2017  Кьево - Торино -...  Ляйич, Дзаппакос...
34   34  29.04.2017  Торино - Сампдор...               Итурбе
35   35  06.05.2017  Ювентус - Торино...                Ляйич
36   36  14.05.2017  Торино - Наполи ...                  NaN
37   37  21.05.2017  Дженоа - Торино ...                Ляйич
38   38  28.05.2017  Торино - Сассуол...  Бойе, Баселли, Д...

[39 rows x 4 columns]
```

Версии модулей:

```
In [64]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.0.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 7
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: C
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.19.2
nose: 1.3.7
pip: 9.0.1
setuptools: 27.2.0
Cython: 0.25.2
numpy: 1.11.3
scipy: 0.18.1
statsmodels: 0.6.1
xarray: 0.9.1
IPython: 5.1.0
sphinx: 1.5.1
patsy: 0.4.1
dateutil: 2.6.0
pytz: 2016.10
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.0
tables: 3.3.0
numexpr: 2.6.1
matplotlib: 2.0.0
openpyxl: 2.4.1
xlrd: 1.0.0
xlwt: 1.2.0
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
lxml: 3.7.2
bs4: 4.5.3
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.1.5
pymysql: 0.7.9.None
psycopg2: 2.7.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
jinja2: 2.9.4
boto: 2.45.0
pandas_datareader: 0.2.1
```

**UPDATE:**

[pd.read_html()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_html.html) использует `lxml` по умолчанию. Если он не установлен или если явно указать `flavor='bs4'` тогда будет использован `bs4`. Проверьте установлен ли у вас модуль `lxml` и если да то какая версия.

> **flavor** : str or None, container of strings
>
> The parsing engine to use. `bs4` and `html5lib` are synonymous with each other, they are
>   both there for backwards compatibility.
>
> The default of None tries to use `lxml` to parse and if that fails it falls back on `bs4` + `html5lib`.

**UPDATE2:** у меня все парсится также с использованием `bs4`:

```
In [5]: dfs = pd.read_html('http://football.kulichki.net/italy/2017/teams/torino.htm', 
                           flavor='bs4')

In [6]: dfs[1]
Out[6]:
     0                   1           2            3   4   5  6  7
0    №             Вратари   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
1    1     Даниэле Паделли  25.10.1985       Италия   2   -  -  -
2   21            Джо Харт  19.04.1987       Англия  36   -  2  -
3   99    Доменико Коппола  29.01.1999       Италия   -   -  -  -
4    №           Защитники   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
5    3   Кристиан Молинаро  30.07.1983       Италия  10   -  2  -
6    4      Леандро Кастан  05.11.1986     Бразилия  14   -  4  -
7    5              Карлао  19.01.1986     Бразилия   4   -  1  -
8    7  Давиде Дзаппакоста  11.06.1992       Италия  29   1  1  -
9   13     Лука Россеттини  09.05.1985       Италия  30   1  8  -
..  ..                 ...         ...          ...  ..  .. .. ..
20  15       Марко Бенасси  08.09.1994       Италия  27   5  5  -
21  16   Самуэль Густафсон  11.01.1995       Швеция   5   -  1  -
22  18   Мирко Вальдифиори  21.04.1986       Италия  24   -  5  -
23  22           Жоэль Оби  22.05.1991      Нигерия  20   -  3  -
24  25          Саша Лукич  13.08.1996       Сербия  14   -  5  -
25   №          Нападающие   Год рожд.  Гражданство   М   Г  Ж  К
26   9      Андреа Белотти  20.12.1993       Италия  35  26  5  -
27  11         Макси Лопес  03.04.1984    Аргентина  16   2  2  -
28  19         Хуан Итурбе  04.06.1993    Аргентина  16   1  1  -
29  31          Лукас Бойе  28.02.1996    Аргентина  30   1  5  -

[30 rows x 8 columns]

In [7]: dfs[2]
Out[7]:
     0               1           2            3    4    5    6    7
0    П          Игроки   Год рожд.  Гражданство    М    Г    Ж    К
1  NaN             NaN         NaN          NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  Хосеф Мартинес  19.05.1993    Венесуэла   11    1    2    -
3  NaN     Чезаре Бово  14.01.1983       Италия    4    -    2    -
4  NaN  Джузеппе Вивес  14.07.1980       Италия    3    -    -    1
5  NaN    Маттиа Араму  14.05.1995       Италия    1    -    -    -
```

**В качестве решения** советую установить [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#linux) в пользоватетельскую директорию и не зависеть от системного Python.

Comment: pandas парсит на указанных html страницах только таблицы?

Comment: @gil9red, да, [pd.read_html(url)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) парсит все `HTML tables` и возвращает `list of DataFrame's`. А что вам надо парсить?

Comment: Я просто люблю парсить и в планах было поиграться с pandas, а тут увидел что он и с html работает :)

Comment: @gil9red, чем больше я изучаю Pandas тем больше он мне нравится :)

Comment: 1. Это видимо баг и его обсуждают http://www.jianshu.com/p/c8c616bc7233   https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1270611 (пишут что причина в bs).                2. У меня отсутствуют 18 модулей, стоящих у вас, наверное дело в этом, а не в версиях имеющихся. Ещё бы понять, какие надо теперь поставить.  И странно, что lxml стоит, пользуюсь им, а pd.show_versions() его не видит (None).

Comment: @БорисМирский, я дополнил ответ...

Comment: Предпринял обходные манёвры.

Попытался извлечь кусок html (таблицу) через regex:
pattern = r'<table ... >(.*)</table>'
match = str(re.findall(pattern, content))
df = pd.read_html(match)
   ошибка та же AttributeError: 'NoneType' object ...

Тогда сделал через lxml и xpath:
tree = fromstring(page)
table = tree.xpath('.//table[@style="border-collapse: separate;"]')
df = []
for i in table:
    x = tostring(i).decode('utf8')
    df.append(pd.read_html(x))
print(df)
наконец получилось

Понимаю, что это говноспособ, но нет времени докапываться до причин бага.